# How to transform or melt column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have this tabular table, but I want to make it into a simple form. The existing form is like this:

```
group      mp_current   mh_current   mp_total   mh_total 
contractor       25         4825        0          0
```

I want to transform the table into this form:

```
group        mp    mh    period
contractor   25   4825   current
contractor   0      0    total
```

where I would have one dedicated column for mp and mh, and one extra column as the period column.

How can I perform this in python?

Answer (score 8):

#### [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

You specify the stubnames (column prefixes), the separator (`'_'`), and that the suffix is anything (`'.*'`) as it by default expects numerics. The `j` argument becomes the column label for the the values after the separator. The column referenced by `i` needs to uniquely label each row.

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, i='group', j='period', 
                       stubnames=['mh', 'mp'], sep='_', suffix='.*')
         .reset_index())
```

---

```
        group   period    mh  mp
0  contractor  current  4825  25
1  contractor    total     0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

As proffered in the previous solution, `wide_to_long` solves this quite well.
An alternative is the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) (they are just wrappers of pandas functions/methods):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(index='group', 
                names_to=('.value', 'period'), 
                names_sep='_')
 
        group   period  mp    mh
0  contractor  current  25  4825
1  contractor    total   0     0
```

The `.value` is an indicator (similar to `stubnames` in `wide_to_long` but much more flexible), informing [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) to retain those parts of the column names associated with it as headers, while the others are collected into the `period` column. Since the column parts are separated by `_`, this is used in the `names_sep` argument. `.value` can be any part of the column names, as long as you can readily identify it with a regular expression (`names_pattern`) or a delimiter (`names_sep`).

You can also pull this off with the `stack` method, where you set an index, split the columns, stack the relevant level and finally reset the index:

```
df = df.set_index('group')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand = True)
df.columns.names = [None, 'period']
df.stack(-1).reset_index()
 
        group   period    mh  mp
0  contractor  current  4825  25
1  contractor    total     0   0
```